# Is the promotion to unsigned done on the result or on each operand?

Tags: c, types, integer, type-conversion, integer-promotion

In the following:
`2147483647U > -2147483647 - 1` it will evaluate to false because of the conversion/promotion to unsigned.
My question is though how it will be promoted?
Will the subtraction operation be done first and the result will be promoted to unsigned or each operand will be promoted to unsigned instead?
Example with 4 bits [-8,7] for signed and [0,15] for unsigned:
`7U > -7 -1`
Will this become (unsigned)(-7) + (unsigned)(-1) = (9U) + (15U) = 24U
So we end up `7U > 24U` which is false.
Or will we have
`-7-1 = -8 = 8U`
So `7U > 8U` which is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression

```
2147483647U > -2147483647 - 1
```

has two operators where minus has a higher priority than logical >.

So at first there is calculated sub-expression

```
-2147483647 - 1
```

The both operands have type int. it is their common type. So neither promotion will be done. You will get

```
-2147483648
```

Then expression

```
2147483647U > -2147483648
```

is evaluated.

Here the common type is unsigned int. Signed and unsigned int have the same rank nevertheless in such cases the common type is unsigned int.

In this expression simply the internal representation of the right operand is interpretated as unsjgned value. So if it is greater than the left operand then the result will be equal to false.

If to consider this example

```
7U > -7 -1
```

then `-7 - 1` will be equal -8. Internal representation of -8 is

```
1000
```

As unsigned int it is equal to 8. Thus

```
7u > 8u
```

is equal to false.

Comment: @Cratylus There is no casting. There is the usual arithmetic conversion, It is applied to operands of an expression.